# A term used to watch how someone performs a task?

Tags: expressions, technical

A term used to watch how someone performs a task ?

Answer (score 2):

To **[observe](https://www.bing.com/search?q=observe&pc=MOZI&form=MOZSBR)**, if you are seeking to understand, or emulate, or amuse curiosity, and such.

> ob·serve
>
> VERB
>
> notice or perceive (something) and register it as being significant.
>       *"young people observe that decisions are made by others"*
>
> watch (someone or something) carefully and attentively.
>           *"Rob stood in the hallway, where he could observe the happenings on the street"*

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on why you want to watch that task being performed at the first place.

1) You're watching how someone performs a task **to be then able to perform that task on your own (=to learn how to perform that task)**

> **work shadowing** noun [ U ] (also job shadowing)
>   the activity of spending time with someone who is doing a particular job so that you can learn how to do it:
>
> *You need to get quality work experience or do some work shadowing.*

2) You're watching how someone performs a task **for your own enjoyment (=because you're curious etc.)**

> **to watch somebody doing something** (also to watch somebody do something)
>
> - watch sb doing sth - to watch how the person is performing the action (it's very likely we see just fragments of the action).
> - watch sb do sth - to watch how the person accomplished the action (we see the whole process).
>
> *I sit by the window and watch people walking past.*
>
> BTW this activity could be described as **people-watching** and the verb for it would be just **to watch people**.
>
> ---
>
> Side note: there is another similarly-looking well-known noun
>
> **clock-watching** noun [ U ] 
>   the act of repeatedly looking to see what time it is in order to see how much longer you have to work. And here's the verb **to watch the clock**

Similarly, if you *really* want to, you could make up your own term for watching the task being performed, like in the case of people-watching (`[thing] - watching`). For example, if you were to use that term in an article, your readers would be familiar with that 'something-watching' compound and what this noun is supposed to mean. Ultimately, it would 'up' the overall impression of the language that you used in that article.